# CGridview Date Range in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii, date-range, cgridview

I would like to use CGridView with Date range in Yii framework , I tried [this one](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/345/how-to-filter-cgridview-with-from-date-and-to-date-datepicker/) and [this also](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/542/cgridview-date-range-without-cookies-or-session-external-filtering/) but it is not working for me,

I have a date column  in my model so I need to use From and To of that date column inside my CGridview.  any help please

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pick a date range using the `edaterangepicker` extension. You can download the extensions from this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/edaterangepicker/)

Comment: Thank you  Sherin Jose, I will try and Let you know.